# Insert or update a user in database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The code uses SQLAlchemy Core. However, what I want to know is if writing code in this pattern is recommendable.

```
def saveUser(self, user):
    """
    Inserts or updates a user in database.
    The method first checks if the provided user's id already exists. If no, then the user will be inserted. Otherwise, the stored values are updated.

    Args:
        user (User)
    Returns:
        User object with inserted id
    """
    result = self._engine.execute(self._userTable.select().where(self._userTable.c.Id == user._id))
    if not result.first():
        # user doesn't exist in database.
        result = self._engine.execute(self._userTable.insert(), Email=user.email, PasswordHash=user.passwordHash,
                                      DisplayName=user.displayName, Active=user.active)
        user._id = result.inserted_primary_key[0]
    else:
        # user already exists in database.
        result = self._engine.execute(self._userTable.update().where(self._userTable.c.Id == user._id),
                                      Email=user.email, PasswordHash=user.passwordHash, DisplayName=user.displayName, Active=user.active)
    return user


def deleteUser(self, userId=None, email=None):
    """
    Deletes a user.
    Either userId or email can be passed. If both are passed, then a user containing both userId and email will be deleted.
    If none of the arguments are provided, then the method call will have not effect.
    Args:
        userId (int): If this is None, only email will be used to delete the user.
        email (str): If this is None, only userId will be used to delete the user.
    """
    if not userId and not email:
        return # Because an empty and_ clause generated later on will raise OperationalError.
    idClause = self._userTable.c.Id == userId if userId else None
    emailClause = self._userTable.c.Email == email if email else None
    finalClause = and_(idClause, emailClause)
    deleteQuery = self._userTable.delete().where(finalClause)
    result = self._engine.execute(deleteQuery)
```

Comment: You don't need to roll your own insert-or-update logic: SQLAlchemy has a [`merge`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_5/session.html#merging) method.

Comment: @GarethRees - Isn't that limited to SQLAlchemy ORM? I am using Core here.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that might make it more Pythonic would be to wrap the body of deleteUser() in a try and catch and handle the OperationalError rather than checking user and email for None before making the attempt.